# ScalingFunctions - reversing a logarithmic axes

Tags: plotting

I have been playing with `ScalingFunctions` in Mathematica 11.0. I wanted to produce a logarithmic scaled plot with the direction reversed. I have had success with accomplishing my goals, but I have no understanding of why it works.

I am able to reverse the axis and/or create a logarithmic axes with out a problem.

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the documentation it talks about using

[image: Mathematica graphics]

as a scaling function and gives an example of

```
{-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}
```

I decided to try it.

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}},
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It produced what I wanted and in one sense that makes this a success. However, I am completely confused by what is going on.

The question is why does supplying `ScalingFunctions` with the negative of a the log and its inverse produce a logarithmic scaled plot with the direction reversed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been curious about what the two different functions do in `ScalingFunctions`.  I think we can get a clue by these two plots

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, #}] & /@ {{# &, 
   Exp[-#] &}, {-Log[#] &, # &}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the first function is applied to the points, and the second function somehow used to construct the tick marks.

Let's look at your example,

```
{regularPlot = Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}],
 reverseLogPlot = 
  Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}}]}
```

We can extract the plotted points from the first, apply `-Log[#]&` to them, and compare that to the points from the scaled plot,

```
list = Cases[regularPlot, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity] // 
  First; reverseLogList = 
 reverseLogPlot // Cases[#, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity] & // First;
ListPlot /@ {reverseLogList, {#1, -Log[#2]} & @@@ list}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and this confirms our suspicions about the first function.

I'm not sure exactly how the second function is applied to the tick marks though.  This isn't quite right:

```
ListLinePlot[{#1, -Log[#2]} & @@@ list,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, NumberForm[Exp[-#], 2]} & /@ 
    Range[-1, 0, .1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

Actually, I have no idea how these functions seem to work, why do these simple examples do nothing?

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, {# + 2 &, # - 2 &}}]
Plot[x, {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, {2 # &, #/2 &}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And why does removing the `PlotRange` option make the first one *almost* work, but the second one fails mysteriously?

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 3}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, {# + 2 &, # - 2 &}}]
Plot[x, {x, -1, 3}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, {2 # &, #/2 &}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is helpful, but I am still confused by the interface.  If the scaling function is monotone, the user should not need to provide the inverse.  Is there a clear use case where being able to provide both arguments is desirable?

Comment: @Alan - actually, now that I look further, I have no idea what these functions do, and I might just delete this answer - why do scaling functions like `{2 # &, #/2 &}` and `{2 + # &, #-2 &}` not work at all?  To answer your question - it would be useful to be able to independently scale the plot and its tick marks.

Comment: @JasonB I am convinced you are on the right track. As you pointed out the `y` values in `reverseLogPlot` are the log of the data. Applying `Cases[reverseLogPlot, Rule[Ticks, x_List] -> x, Infinity]` results in `{{Automatic, Charting\`ScaledTicks[{-Log[#1] &, Exp[-#1] &}]`. It needs to apply the inverse in order to get the ticks to come out right. It apparently uses some sophistication as it uses a package function `Charting\`ScaledTicks`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne - I remember trying to figure out `ScaledTicks` as well, and giving up.  I wanted, just like here, to start at the simplest example:  `{2#, #/2}` or `{# +2, # -2}`.   And they failed there also

Comment: Your guess for the usage of the last syntax of `ScalingFunctions` is correct, and your last 4 examples have worked as expected actually. Try `Plot[x, {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, {2 # &, #/2 &}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]` and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: @Alan I think the main point of specifying both the function and its inverse might be simply to not have to guess the inverse of a pure function. Of course they could have added yet another syntax for specifying only the function without its inverse, but then people will start complaining about that form not working/being extremely slow in some cases that they think are simple

Comment: I've been using your answer to figure out how `ScalingFunctions` work, and I think I understand it now. What did you expect to see in your last two examples? The thing is, the scaling functions you use cannot be noticed as your revert ticks and scale is automatically adjusted by the aspect ratio.