# ListDensityPlot with Logarithmic plotlegends and ScalingFunctions

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

With Mathematica 11.3. (11.0 has some bug in ScalingFunctions).

I use Jason B.'s method, i.e. ScalingFunction ( see [Logarithmic scale in a DensityPlot and its legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/logarithmic-scale-in-a-densityplot-and-its-legend/36831#36831)).

Jason B.'s code

```
sf = Log[#/0.00003]/Log[1/0.00003] &;
isf = InverseFunction[sf];
g1 = DensityPlot[Sinc[x]^2 Sinc[y]^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf}, 
ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", PlotRange -> {0.00003, 1}, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", 
{0.00003, 1}}, ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf}], ImageSize -> 300]
```

the result is

[image]

Let me have a check,

```
d = 0.25;
g2 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{-17, 0}, d], Red, Disk[{-17, 10}, d], Red, 
Disk[{-10, 0}, d], Red, Disk[{-4.5, 0}, d], Red, 
Disk[{-4.5, 5}, d], Red, Disk[{-4.5, 14}, d], Red, 
Disk[{0, 4.5}, d], Red, Disk[{0, 10}, d]}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, ImageSize -> 300];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]

```
N[Sinc[x]^2 Sinc[y]^2 /. {{x -> -17, y -> 0}, {x -> -17, 
y -> 10}, {x -> -10, y -> 0}, {x -> -4.5, y -> -0}, {x -> -4.5, 
y -> 5}, {x -> -4.5, y -> 14}, {x -> 0, y -> 4.5}, {x -> 0, 
y -> 10}}]
```

the output is

```
{0.00319822, 9.46541*10^-6, 0.00295959, 0.0471884, 0.00173566, 0.000236256, 
 0.0471884, 0.00295959}
```

so fig1 seems correct.

Now I turn to the ListDensityPlot,

```
test = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sinc[x]^2 Sinc[y]^2}, {x, -20, 20, 0.2}, {y, 
-20, 20, 0.2}], 1];
Dimensions[test]
n = Dimensions[test][[1]];
Min[test[[;; , 3]]]
Max[test[[;; , 3]]]

\[Eta] = 0.00003;
min1 = Chop[Min[test[[;; , 3]]]] + \[Eta];
max1 = Max[test[[;; , 3]]] + \[Eta];

sf = Log[(#)/min1]/Log[max1/min1] &;
(*Function[x,Log[(x)/min1]/Log[max1/min1]];*)
isf = InverseFunction[sf];
g3=ListDensityPlot[test, PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf},
ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", PlotRange -> {min1, max1}, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", 
{min1, max1}}, ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf}]]
```

[image]

Firstly, I don't understand the ScalingFunctions->{sf,isf}, so I rescale the data myself,

```
dat1 = Table[{0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, n}];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
{
dat1[[i, 1]] = test[[i, 1]];
dat1[[i, 2]] = test[[i, 2]];
dat1[[i, 3]] = Log[(Chop[test[[i, 3]]])/min1]/Log[max1/min1]
}]
 g4 = ListDensityPlot[dat1, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", {min1, max1}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf}], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Finally , compare above results

```
GraphicsGrid[{{g1, g3, g4}}, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]

The results look nice.

Finally, make ticks in scientific form

```
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"DeepSeaColors", {min1, max1}}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf}, 
Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, DisplayForm@SuperscriptBox[10, i]}, {i, 
IntegerPart[Log10[min1]], IntegerPart[Log10[max1]], 1}], {min1, 
max1}}]
```

[image]

---

ScalingFunctions->{f,f^-1}, f operates on the "data", suppose the data (x,y),
then (x,f(y)), and f^-1 operates on the y axis, so f^(-1)(f(y)) is invariant, more detailed ,please see [ScalingFunctions - reversing a logarithmic axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126290/scalingfunctions-reversing-a-logarithmic-axes/176154?noredirect=1#comment462293_176154)

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you have? Starting with 11.0 or so, [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) does what you want

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]. 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).

Comment: @LukasLang Mathematica 11. Could you please explain what does ScalingFunctions->{f,f^-1} mean? Jason B’s method is good, but I don’t understand this f,f^-1 even I read the document.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your `test`. Using your code I obtained the desired result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTfnZ.png I've made no modification.

Comment: "xzczd can obtain the reasonable fig with my code, but I can't ,why? (He's mathematica 11.2, and my 11.0). " I won't be surprised if there's a bug being fixed in this period. "It seems very similar with fig.1, but not the same, some value is wrong. " No, nothing is wrong, notice your definition of `sf` is different from Jason B.'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @xzczd, I upgrade my mathematica to 11.3 and solve this problem.

Comment: Please move the solution to your problem to an answer. Answering your own question is perfectly fine and thanks for taking the time to post your solution!